# what is the difference in writing styles of these 2 queries?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-delete, sqlperformance

I am using MS SQL Server 2012:

The two queries are:

1:

```
with cte as
(

<some code>
)
delete p from table p join cte on p.id=cte.id
and p.date>cte.date
```

2:

```
with cte as
(

<some code>
)
delete p from table p join cte on cte.id=p.id
and cte.date>p.date
```

The difference in two queries is writing the join condition of either of the table columns first.

How should I decide which is efficient or correct?

Comment: `p.date>cte.date` and `cte.date>p.date` are two completely different things

Comment: You mean `cte.date<p.date`? Still the same thing though.

Answer (score 4):

The equality `=` operator is symetric. Flipping the order of the operands doesn't have any functional or performance impact.

The greater than (`>`) operator, on the other hand, is, of course, not symertic. `p.date>cte.date` and `cte.date>p.date` are functionally different, and you should choose the correct one according to your business logic, regardless of performance. No matter how fast a `delete` statement runs, if it's deleting the wrong thing, it's pretty useless (not to mention down right harmful).

Comment: Notice p.date>cte.date and cte.date>p.date

Comment: @GiorgiNakeuri Just noticed that myself, and amended my answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Using the **= Operator** : 
u can write condition either side of `=` remains the same 
like
 `**A=B or B=A**` .  Both will give same results.

**<,> Comparison operator:**'

It wil make different results when we comparing opposite side

like `A<B and B<A` both outputs are different.

**Conclusion:** Its yours choice to choose first or second option based on your business needs.**Using CTE will always boost performance**.